# ESP8266 sketch worked a few times but now doesn't seem to run

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, wifi, sketch, web-server

When I flash my code:

```
/* Create a WiFi access point and provide a web server on it. 

 Author: Lucio A. Rocha
 Last Update: 21 Aug 2016

*/

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h> 
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

/* Set these to your desired credentials. */
const char *ssid = "MaisonBlanche";
const char *password = "7932gLBw";

ESP8266WebServer server(80);

const int led = 2;  //GPIO2

/* Just a little test message.  Go to http://192.168.4.1 in a web browser
 * connected to this access point to see it.
 */
void handleRoot() {

  int size=1000;
  char temp[size];

  int sec = millis() / 1000;
  int min = sec / 60;
  int hr = min / 60;

  snprintf ( temp, size,

"<html>\
  <head>\    
    <title>MicroCloud</title>\
    <style>\
      body { background-color: #cccccc; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif; Color: #000088; }\
    </style>\
  </head>\
  <body>\
    <h3>You are connected on MicroCloud #2!</h3>\
    <p>Uptime: %02d:%02d:%02d</p>\    
    <p>Status: Light ON</h1></p>\
    <p><a href=\"http://192.168.4.1/on\"><h1>Turn ON</h1></a></p>\
    <p></p>\
    <p><a href=\"http://192.168.4.1/off\"><h1>Turn OFF</h1></a></p>\           
  </body>\
</html>",

    hr, min % 60, sec % 60
  );
  server.send ( 200, "text/html", temp );  

}

void setup() {
  delay(1000);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Configuring access point...");

  /* You can remove the password parameter if you want the AP to be open. */
  WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);

  IPAddress myIP = WiFi.softAPIP();
  Serial.print("AP IP address: ");
  Serial.println(myIP);

  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite ( led, HIGH );

  //URLs available to query
  server.on("/", handleRoot);
  server.on ( "/on", turnON );    
  server.on ( "/off", turnOFF );
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");

}

void turnON(){

  digitalWrite ( led, HIGH );

  int size=1000;
  char temp[size];

  int sec = millis() / 1000;
  int min = sec / 60;
  int hr = min / 60;

  snprintf ( temp, size,

"<html>\
  <head>\    
    <title>MicroCloud</title>\
    <style>\
      body { background-color: #cccccc; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif; Color: #000088; }\
    </style>\
  </head>\
  <body>\
    <h3>Request: Light ON</h3>\
    <p>Uptime: %02d:%02d:%02d</p>\
    <p></p>\
    <p>Status: Light ON</h1></p>\
    <p><a href=\"http://192.168.4.1/on\"><h1>Turn ON</h1></a></p>\
    <p></p>\
    <p><a href=\"http://192.168.4.1/off\"><h1>Turn OFF</h1></a></p>\       
  </body>\
</html>",

    hr, min % 60, sec % 60
  );

  server.send ( 200, "text/html", temp);

}

void turnOFF(){

  digitalWrite ( led, LOW );

  int size=1000;
  char temp[size];

  int sec = millis() / 1000;
  int min = sec / 60;
  int hr = min / 60;

  snprintf ( temp, size,

"<html>\
  <head>\    
    <title>MicroCloud</title>\
    <style>\
      body { background-color: #cccccc; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif; Color: #000088; }\
    </style>\
  </head>\
  <body>\
    <h3>Request: Light OFF</h3>\
    <p>Uptime: %02d:%02d:%02d</p>\
    <p>Status: Light OFF</p>\
    <p><a href=\"http://192.168.4.1/on\"><h1>Turn ON</h1></a></p>\
    <p></p>\
    <p><a href=\"http://192.168.4.1/off\"><h1>Turn OFF</h1></a></p>\       
  </body>\
</html>",

    hr, min % 60, sec % 60
  );

  server.send ( 200, "text/html", temp);

}

void loop() {
  server.handleClient();
}
```

onto the ESP8266 with this setup:

[image]

For my serial output I get:

```
en 1384, room 16 
tail 8
chksum 0x2d
csum 0x2d
v09f0c112
~ld
```

I got it to work semi successfully before now. I was basically following along with https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/luciorocha/esp8266-control-led-with-smartphone-8a59f3. I got to the point where the code was being run successfully - but then something unexpected happened, when I thought the LED would go on, when I selected the `turn on` button, nothing happened. When I selected `turn off`, the blue LED on the board turned on and stayed steady. Then, when I selected `turn on` again, the LED on board went off. I thought the sketch was supposed to manipulate pin 2, but it seemed to be manipulating the onboard LED instead, and in the reverse way that it should.

Now, I can upload it, but the only thing it does after that is spit out the above serial output. I have tried running it with:

```
GND -> GND
VCC -> 3.3v
CH_PD -> 3.3v
```

Other sketches seem to work, so maybe something I did triggered an ESP8266 setting which now conflicts with something in the code?

**UPDATE**

I double checked that other sketches are running - also running is a sketch that connects the ESP8266 to my network - it connects and gets assigned an IP. I made this simplified sketch of the one above, involving the connection process:

```
/* Create a WiFi access point and provide a web server on it. 

 Author: Lucio A. Rocha
 Last Update: 21 Aug 2016

*/

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h> 

void setup() {
  delay(1000);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Configuring access point...");

  /* You can remove the password parameter if you want the AP to be open. */
  WiFi.softAP("MaisonBlanche", "7932gLBw");

  IPAddress myIP = WiFi.softAPIP();
  Serial.print("AP IP address: ");
  Serial.println(myIP);
}

void loop() {

}
```

The only thing it outputs (no connection) to serial is:

```
0, len 1384, room 16 
tail 8
chksum 0x2d
csumcL⸮
~ld
```

So it seems as if the problem is with my code, or it is able to connect to a network as a client but not as a `softAP`?

**UPDATE**

I ran this code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

ESP8266WebServer server(80);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();

  Serial.print("Setting soft-AP ... ");
  boolean result = WiFi.softAP("MaisonBlanche", "7932gLBw");
  if(result == true)
  {
    Serial.println("Ready");
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Failed!");
  }
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.printf("Stations connected = %d\n", WiFi.softAPgetStationNum());
  delay(3000);
}
```

The same garbled serial output appears, and then it started outputting:

`Stations connected = 0`

Then the output changed to:

`Stations connected = 1`

Does this just mean it is successfully connecting using `softAP`?

**UPDATE**

I think I have narrowed it down what is not working to the `ESP8266WebServer`. I used this code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

ESP8266WebServer server(80);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();

  Serial.print("Setting soft-AP ... ");
  boolean result = WiFi.softAP("MaisonBlanche", "7932gLBw");
  if(result == true)
  {
    Serial.println("Ready");
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Failed!");
  }

  server.on("/", handleRoot);
  server.begin();
}

void handleRoot() {

  int size=1000;
  char temp[size];

  int sec = millis() / 1000;
  int min = sec / 60;
  int hr = min / 60;

  snprintf ( temp, size,

    "<html>\
      <head>\    
        <title>BEASTMODE</title>\
        <style>\
          body { background-color: #cccccc; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif; Color: #000088; }\
        </style>\
      </head>\
      <body>\
        <h3>You are connected on BEASTMODE!</h3>\    
      </body>\
    </html>",

    hr, min % 60, sec % 60
  );
  server.send ( 200, "text/html", temp );  
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.printf("Stations connected = %d\n", WiFi.softAPgetStationNum());
  //delay(3000);
  Serial.print("Soft-AP IP address = ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.softAPIP());
  server.handleClient();
}
```

When the loop starts it begins to output:

```
Soft-AP IP address = 192.168.4.1
Stations connected = 0
```

It seems to go between 0 stations connected and 1 station connected. I go to 192.168.1.4 in my browser, and it never loads the page, it just times out. So if it has a `softAP` IP address - but it is not accessible, then maybe the server isn't working for some reason. Also I read how you can put the chip into different modes (STA/AP/etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/esp8266wifi/server-examples.html?highlight=WebServer) works fine, doesn't use ESP8266WebServer which seems to be the culprit. It is the web server from `ESP8266WiFi`. At the bottom there is a link to a blinking LED example which works for me. You just type in `<ip>/gpio/0` in browser for off, and change it to `/gpio/1` for on.

Comment: Accept your own answer to close this question.